# VBA - Add Sheets based on a value and name accodingly

Tags: vba, excel

I am having trouble with my code.  I need to create new sheets and name them according to the name of a machine.  Which is the range `"B" & (12 * x - 5)`.  Yes the range changes based on `x` which in this example is equal to 1 to 33, and is within the proper `For` statement.   However my code is creating a large number of sheets and not just 11, in this example.  `Sheets("Tool Setup").Range("C18") = 11` in this example.  Also, my intention is to name these sheets according to the value in Range `"B" & (12 * x - 5)`.

```
Dim Sheetcnt As Integer, Tabs As Integer
Sheet = ThisWorkbook.Names(Sheets("Reporting").Range("B" & (12 * x - 5))).RefersToRange.Value
Sheetcnt = Sheets("Tool Setup").Range("C18")

For Tabs = 1 To Sheetcnt
    Sheets.Add After:=Sheets(Sheets.Count) 'creates a new worksheet
    Sheets(Sheets.Count).Name = Sheet 'renames the new worksheet
Next Tabs
```

If someone can help me figure out how to create a code that will satisfy this problem, it would be much appreciated.  I have a hunch it has to do with the variable `Tabs`.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: you do not define x, I believe you mean to reference `Tabs`

Comment: you also do not give the newly added sheet a name, unless your intention was to give them default names `Sheet1`, `Sheet2`, etc

Comment: `Dim Sheet as Integer` is a terribly misleading name to give to a variable that doesn't contain a `Worksheet` object reference. `sheetCount` perhaps? What's in `'Tool Setup'!C18`? FWIW whatever is in there would probably be better off as a named range, e.g. `Sheet = ThisWorkbook.Names("SomeConfigurationValue").RefersToRange.Value`

Comment: `Tabs` is never assigned to (at least in the code you posted), so its value will always be `0`. What's that hunch about?

Comment: I don't think your question can be answered as-is. Please [edit] to clarify. See [mcve] if you're not sure how.

Comment: I believe I edited it the best that I could for better help.  I am sorry if I am unclear, I am quite new at VBA

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on what you've provided, I've come up with the code below which names 11 sheets according to a formula similar to yours. To demonstrate that it works, I placed consecutive numbers in the first 127 rows of Column B of the active sheet.  Then, the code calculates which row to grab using the formula `Range("B" & (12 * i - 5)` That formula gives the following sequence: 7 19  31  43  55  67  79  91  103 115 127, and so 11 sheets with those numbers are made.

If this is not what you intended, perhaps you can use this working code as a place from which to start. Or, better yet, provide more definition for your question.

```
Option Explicit
Sub sheetNamer()
    Dim num As Integer, i As Integer, sh As Worksheet
    num = 11
    Set sh = ActiveSheet
    For i = 1 To num
        Sheets.Add After:=Sheets(Sheets.Count)
        Sheets(Sheets.Count).Name = sh.Range("B" & (12 * i - 5))
    Next i
End Sub
```

Comment: Please be sure to properly indent your code when posting :).

Comment: It's good you are going through the code line by line. Also check the values of key variables by hovering your mouse over them, or if that doesn't work, adding lines of code such as "s=num", or "s=sh.name", etc... (where s is declared as "Dim s as String"). If it is skipping over the "For" statement then "num" must be 1 or less. If it won't name the sheet then first define another variable "Dim shName as String" and then replace the code naming the sheet with these lines "shName=sh.Range("B" & (12 * i - 5))" followed by "Sheets(Sheets.Count).Name=shName" & check the value of shName

Comment: @Tony I attempted it and since `num` will change with other data. I attempted to set sh = Sheets("Tool Setup") and `num = sh.Range("C18").Value`. Also since I've previously used `i` as a variable I changed it to `j`. However, It won't name the sheets.  It skips over that line of code. I also switched num line with Set

Comment: @ACohen If it is skipping over it then the issue is likely that `i > num` and if you mean that you replaced `num` with `Set` then you need to change `Set` to something else (since `Set` is an assignment operator).

Comment: @TonyM So now it creates 11 slides, and gives me the names of them, but only four of them and places a buffer slide between them. `"CorrectName1"` -- `Sheet2` -- `Sheet3` -- `"CorrectName2"`

Comment: @ACohen It's possible some of the names you are using contain illegal characters.  To find out what the problem is, go through line-by-line while continually checking the values of variables just before they are used. I tried to describe how to do that in my previous comment so that you can learn how to solve problems like this.  If you can learn how to do that, you'll find VBA very powerful. When addressing questions on this site it's best to eventually consider the problem solved since otherwise the problem continually changes, losing the original focus. Hope you feel you've been helped

Comment: @TonyM I do appreciate the help and the assistance to teaching me.  However, they are not illegal characters, and the names are going down the line of names correctly, It is just adding the names after two newly created sheets rather than 1 after the other.  Thank you nonetheless.

Comment: When strange things like this happen I try to go back to a point where the code was working as expected.  For example, in my original code, there was no skipping of sheets. Then gradually introduce lines of code so that you can pinpoint where the unexpected behavior begins. If, for some reason a sheet doesn't get named when you think it should, try naming the sheet with that text manually.